# How to dynamically extract both negative and positive numbers from a textfile?

Tags: c++, parsing, split

I have obtained a line in textfile that says for example:

> XCoordRange=0-8

Now that would be easy, i can just do a simple `ifstream` and read it to a `string line` and proceed to map and convert

line[12] to `int x1`

and line[14] to `int x2`.

This way, i am able to parse the values into my `x1` and `x2` coordinates.

However, things get tricky when different scenarios appear such as :

> XCoordRange=-10--5 (both negative)
>
> XCoordRange=-10-5  (one negative and one positive)
>
> XCoordRange=10--5  (one positive and one negative)

So my question is how can i dynamically map numbers in different scenarios into my `x1` and `x2`?

It seems as though i can only read one type of data (negative or positive) and not both (negative and positive).

Below is what i've tried so far:

```
    string line = "XCoordRange=-10-5";  
    size_t pos = 0;     
    string token;   
    string delimiter = "=";

    if(pos = line.find(delimiter) != string::npos)
    {
                    token = line.substr(0, pos);
                    line.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }
```

This gives me an output of `-10--5`, however, i am stuck in what i should do next.

Comment: The first line should be string line = "XCoordRange=-10--5"; with quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `istringstream` defined in `<sstream>` as follows

```
// if line is "-10--5"
std::istringstream iss(line);
int n1, n2;
iss >> n1; // read first number ("-10")
iss.ignore(); // ignore the '-' character
iss >> n2; // read the second number ("-5")
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: If you want to use the `stringstream` to get `token` as well, you use: `std::getline(iss, token, '=');`

Comment: Will give it a try as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
   size_t equalPos = line.find("=");
   size_t dashPos = line.find("-", equalPos + 2);
   int x1 = stoi(line.substr(equalPos + 1, dashPos - equalPos - 1));
   int x2 = stoi(line.substr(dashPos + 1));
```

Of course, if you're not sure that the string `line` will always match the given pattern, then you need to add some checks.